# Upload base64 encoded image using HttPost and HttpClient

Tags: android, image, http-post, multipart

I try to upload an image (base64 encoded) alongside with other values to a PHP webserver, which takes this information and does some further processing.

The folowing functions are part of an AsyncTask, which executes the request.

I build the postData by hand concatenating the different values.

The JsonUrlLook class helps me finding the correct URL for sending the data to. I verified it. It is correct.

When I try to execute the created HttpPost my response is null. Anybody an idea why this is?

```
private String getPostData(String arrayString, String base64Image, String boundary) {
    String remoteMethod = "uploadPic";
    String postData = "";

    // Add remote method name
    postData += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + boundary + "[method]\"\r\n\r\n";
    postData += remoteMethod;

    postData += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + boundary + "[params]\"\r\n\r\n";
    postData += arrayString;

    postData += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + boundary + "\"\r\n\r\n";
    postData += "filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n";
    postData += base64Image;

    postData += "--" + boundary + "--";

    return postData;
}

private String uploadPicture(String arrayString, String base64Image) {

    String boundary = "tx_fpoemobile_pi2";

    // Get post data
    String postData = getPostData(arrayString, base64Image, boundary);

    // Get webservice uri
    JsonUrlLookup lookup = new JsonUrlLookup(context);
    URL webserviceUrl = lookup.buildUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.page_uid_webservice));
    URI webserviceUri = null;
    try {
        webserviceUri = new URI(webserviceUrl.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }

    // Build client and post
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webserviceUri);

    // Set header of post
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length()));

    // Set body
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO
    }

    return "uploadPictureSuccess";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work like this

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);
    
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

## for getting response

```
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));



String sResponse;
while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) 
 {
     s = s.append(sResponse);
 }

 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
 {
     return s.toString();
 }else
 {
     return "{\"status\":\"false\",\"message\":\"Some error occurred\"}";
 }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In place of image you can send anything.

In this case you need `httpmime-4.2.1-1.jar`

Comment: I said that I need to transfer the image as base64 encoded string and not as binary. But anyhow, I will try your solution.

Comment: Would you mind to explain the function "writeParamData"?

Comment: In your post "for getting response" you use a httpClient and a httpPost with a set entity. This differs a lot form the first part. Do they connect, or are these completely different approches. I dont get it.

Comment: It's almost similar to your code .. I just divided them for better understanding

Comment: How bout the method "writeParamData"? How would I do that?

Comment: check this link http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check tomorrow, and come back to you.